# Column (name) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined)

Tags: java, informix

I am getting below exception while reading data from informix database:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column (name) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
```

I am just executing simple `select` statement using jpql without `where` clause.
Can someone please share inputs.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "History")
public class History extends ZSVParentEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String category;


  @Column(name = "category", length = 80)
  public String getcategory;() {
    return category;
  }
```

I tried to read as below:

```
Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(jpaQl);

if (bindParams != null && bindParams.size() > 0) {
  for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : bindParams.entrySet()) {
    query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
  }
}
return query.getResultList();
```

and it failed at `return query.getResultList();`

Please let me know what other detail is required.

Comment: Please provide code of what you are using that throws that Exception

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, and about how to create an MCVE [([MCVE]) now! There's no way to help unless you show the SQL that is causing the error, and probably the schemas of the tables referenced in the query. Was it actually `name` that was specified in the error message, or did you change that when you copied the message? Basically, at the point (or one of the points) where you use the specified name (almost certainly a plain name without a table alias prefix — just `name` and not `alias.name`), there is no table that contains the named column.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the suggestion. As mentioned, i am using direct sql statement " select * from history" . The table history already has "category" column in it.  Still it is giving me exception. Please let me know in case more detailed inputs ate required. will do so

Comment: Basically, until I see the table definition, or a subset of the full table definition that generates the error, and the actual SELECT sent to the server — as opposed to what 'jpql' was given (I'm not entirely sure what jpql is) — it is going to be hard to know what could be going wrong.  The exact error message would be helpful too; you mention 'name' in the question and 'category' in your response.  Is there any risk that jpql is doing anything nasty like setting DELIMIDENT and then quoting column names and you have a column '`category`' but it refers to `"Category"`, or something silly?

Comment: If you query really is `SELECT * FROM history`, there really isn't much excuse for complaining as there are no column names.  So, is jpql expanding that into `SELECT …, category, … FROM history`?  Without seeing the exact text, I have to speculate, which is frustrating.  Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]). In an SQL question, a minimal table schema (just the columns mentioned explicitly, and maybe one or two extra if they exist) and some sample data (5-10 rows) are helpful. Clearly, when the SQL doesn't execute, you don't get a result, but show the expected output for the sample data.

Comment: i have provided the details. Please check and let me k´now in case i missed something

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and include the full exception stacktrace.